# Garbage collection of finished, unreferenced Timers

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, garbage-collection

So I've got a Timer something like:

```
private var timer:Timer;

public function doThingLater():void {
    timer = new Timer(1000, 1);

    var someBigThing:SomeBigThing = new SomeBigThing();

    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function():void {
        someBigThing.doThing();
        timer = null;
    });
    timer.start();
}
```

and I need to be sure that someBigThing is garbage-collected.

My google results keep telling me that if a Timer never stops, it will never be collected, but what about ones that do stop?

And I'm fairly certain that just setting the field to null doesn't necessarily allow for collection; if I have this instead:

```
public function doThingLater():void {
    //initialize timer...
    timer.start();
    timer = null;
}
```

I still expect the timer to run.

I know could make sure it's collected by calling removeEventListener on the Timer, but the listener is anonymous; obviously I could make this work, but I think anonymous listeners are more readable.

Comment: In that case it can't since start() is not called meaning the iistener will never run. If you call start() then the timer will be set to null after it runs and should qualify for GC as it should.

Comment: You're right, I forgot start(). But I'm unsure that just because I'm changing a reference to null, it will be collected; if I start a Timer and then the Timer goes out of scope, it's still there, right?

Comment: it's still there but it qualifies for gc which will happen at a later time, maybe 1 second later maybe one minute. That's why removing listeners is indispensable. If using anonymous function which cannot be directly removed it's important to set the weakReference argument to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so I did a little experimentation to see what I could find, my code is below. I'm not 100% certain on any of this, but my main points of discovery are:

- Yes, stopped Timers will eventually be collected.
- Removing the listener works just as well.
- Using weakly referenced listeners would work too, so long as another reference to the listener is maintained until its no longer needed.

In experimentation, I also came to other somewhat less relevant conclusions:

- When garbage collection works is difficult to predict, even when forcing it with `System.gc()`
- An anonymous function copies the *entire* activation record for the current function, which leads to two other troubling conclusions:
- Anonymous functions may hold unexpected references to objects, so the function returned from

  ```
  function foo():Function {
      var thing:Object;
      //initialize thing

      //Do a bunch of other stuff.

      return function():void { /*do nothing*/ };
  }
  ```

  stops `thing` from being garbage collected.
- Anonymous functions reference the original local variables so

  ```
  var thing:SomeClass;

  var function:Function = function():void {
      thing.doAThing();
  };

  //do some stuff

  thing = null;
  ```

  will result in a null reference error if `function` is ever used.

I'll wait a couple days to see if someone with a solid understanding of how Timers are collected comes along, and then accept my own answer. Anyway, here's that test code:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.system.System;

    import flash.utils.Dictionary;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public static var objects:Dictionary;

        private var control:Vector.<int>;

        private var doesNotStop:Timer;
        private var stops:Timer;
        private var removesListener:Timer;
        private var usesWeakListener:Timer;

        private static var before:Timer, after:Timer;

        private static var beforeTime:Number = 100;
        private static var time:Number = 1000;
        private static var afterTime:Number = 2000;
        private static var wellAfterTime:Number = 6000;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init(null);
            else
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }
        public function init(event:Event):void {
            doIt();

            printObjects("After releasing references, ");

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, test);
        }

        public function test(event:Event):void {
            printObjects("On key press, ");
        }
        public function doIt():void {

            objects = new Dictionary(true);

            //Create objects.
            var thing:Vector.<int> = createBigObject();

            control = createBigObject();

            var stopsObject:Object = initializeStops();

            var doesNotStopObject:Object = initializeDoesNotStop();

            var removesListenerObject:Object = initializeRemovesListener();

            var usesWeakListenerObject:Object = initializeUsesWeakListener();

            //Add them to the dictionary.
            objects[control] = "control";

            objects[thing] = "thing";

            objects[doesNotStop] = "does not stop";
            objects[doesNotStopObject] = "does not stop object";

            objects[stops] = "stops";
            objects[stopsObject] = "stops object";


            objects[removesListener] = "removes listener";
            objects[removesListenerObject] = "removes listener object";

            objects[usesWeakListener] = "uses weak listener";
            objects[usesWeakListenerObject] = "uses weak listener object";

            printObjects("Before releasing references, ");

            //Release local references.
            control = null;

            doesNotStop = null;
            doesNotStopObject = null;

            stops = null;
            stopsObject = null;

            removesListener = null;
            removesListenerObject = null;

            usesWeakListener = null;
            usesWeakListenerObject = null;


            //Start timers to check gc later.
            before = new Timer(beforeTime, 1);
            var listener:Function =  function():void {
                printObjects("Before the Timer has finished, ");
            };
            before.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, listener, false, 0, false);
            before.start();

            after = new Timer(afterTime, 1);
            after.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function():void {
                printObjects("After the Timer has finished, ");
            });
            after.start();

            var wellAfter:Timer = new Timer(wellAfterTime, 1);
            wellAfter.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function():void {
                printObjects("Well after the Timer has finished, ");
            });
            wellAfter.start();
        }

        private function initializeDoesNotStop():Object {
            var object:Vector.<int> = createBigObject();

            doesNotStop = new Timer(time, 0);
            doesNotStop.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function():void {
                object[0] = 10;
            });
            doesNotStop.start();

            return object;
        }

        private function initializeStops():Object {
            var object:Vector.<int> = createBigObject();

            stops = new Timer(time, 1);
            stops.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function():void {
                object[0] = 10;
            });
            stops.start();

            return object;
        }

        private function initializeRemovesListener():Object {
            var object:Vector.<int> = createBigObject();

            var listener:Function = function(event:Event):void {
                object[0] = 10;
                (event.target as Timer).removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, listener);
            };

            removesListener = new Timer(time, 1);
            removesListener.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, listener);
            removesListener.start();

            return object;
        }

        private function initializeUsesWeakListener():Object {
            var object:Vector.<int> = createBigObject();

            usesWeakListener = new Timer(time, 1);
            usesWeakListener.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function():void {
                object[0] = 10;
            }, false, 0, true);
            usesWeakListener.start();

            return object;
        }

        public static function createBigObject():Vector.<int> {
            var out:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>(100, true);
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 100; i++)
                out[i] = i;

            return out;
        }

        public static function printObjects(msg:String):void {

            System.gc();

            var output:String = msg + "the following objects have not been collected: ";

            var objectNames:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();

            for each (var value:String in objects) {
                objectNames.push(value);
            }

            objectNames.sort(0);

            for each (var str:String in objectNames) {
                output += str + ", ";
            }

            trace(output);
        }

    }

}
```

I pasted that in, so be careful of formatting issues should you test it yourself.
The output was:

Before releasing references, the following objects have not been collected: control, does not stop, does not stop object, removes listener, removes listener object, stops, stops object, thing, uses weak listener, uses weak listener object,

After releasing references, the following objects have not been collected: control, does not stop, does not stop object, removes listener, removes listener object, stops, stops object, thing, uses weak listener, uses weak listener object,

Before the Timer has finished, the following objects have not been collected: does not stop, does not stop object, removes listener, removes listener object, stops, stops object, thing, uses weak listener,

After the Timer has finished, the following objects have not been collected: does not stop, does not stop object, removes listener, removes listener object, stops, stops object, thing, uses weak listener,

Well after the Timer has finished, the following objects have not been collected: does not stop, does not stop object, thing,

On key press, the following objects have not been collected: does not stop, does not stop object, thing,